# Do I need to update the table view manually after calling performFetch in a Core Data app?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

I'm new to this Core Data business.

I got a UITableViewController hooked up with a NSFetchedResultsController. In `viewDidLoad`, I fire a request to get necessary data from the server, then use `[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]` to update the table view. All works fine until that point.

Now I want to move the data fetching stuff to another thread, so after the app received a NSArray object from the server, it performs the `didFinishFetchingItems` selector on the main thread. In that selector, I save the NSArray to the Core Data store and have the `fetchedResultsController` perform a fetch. No data show up, although a `NSLog` reveals that the data is still there (e.g. `[[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]` returns 100). I have to put a `[self.tableView reloadData]` at the end of the method to refresh the table view manually.

My question is: What have I done wrong? Why did I need to do the table view refreshing manually?

Comment: My understanding is that you should do [fetchedRequestController performFetch] only once for initial loading of the data. Beyond that, it's all about the delegate updating the data as I describe in my answer.

Comment: I run into exactly same problem yesterday. I guess the FRC delegate methods boiler plate code in Apple doc might have some blind points causing it not update table view as expected under some circumstances. Do you have a better understanding on the issue now? I would be very glad to hear your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to refresh anything manually; fetchedResultsController does that for you.

What you need to do is to implement NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate for some object, and set that object as the delegate for your fetchedresultscontroller.

See [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) about what you need to implement. If your model is simple, you can pretty much copy-paste that code into your delegate and everything works.

The important thing is to keep both the resultscontroller and other pieces of code working against the same managed object context. This is how the resultscontroller can pick up the changes. But, in Core Data guide, there are some caveats about multithreading, so make sure you have your threading bases covered and then all works.

Comment: I think the problem is with my multi threading code, since I don't have to reload the table view manually when operating in a single thread. Haven't found out what's wrong with it, though.

Answer (score 2):

You should not touch your NSFetchedResultsController in a non-main thread, that is not a thread-safe operation.

If you are having a long delay on fetching then you need to do a background fetch using a separate NSManagedObjectContext.  If you perform a separate fetch in the background it will load the data into cache and then the NSFetchedResultsController will hit the cache instead of disk, speeding up retrieval on the main thread.

Comment: you mean "using a separate NSManagedObjectContext"?